# Выполнение задачи для всех пользователей

Tags: xml, cmd, администрирование

Есть файл с расширением .cmd, он должнен импортировать задачу для последующего её выполнения, выглядит он примерно так: 
`schtasks /create /xml F:\folder\folder1\name.xml /tn name`
А XML файл, который он преобразует в задачу, выглядит ~так:
[XML-код на Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Lul0vvr44D8EG7w8BQdMeffsQ0ZgJRcER-eRll0GHf0/edit?usp=sharing)
Здесь он с малым интервалом открывает для примера Фотошоп. Суть проблемы: эту задачу нужно импортировать на другие ПК через носитель, но у меня нет возможности изменять задачу в планировщике, ровно как и узнать имена устройств. В XML-файле четко указан мой компьютер и имя пользователя, соответственно комп, на котром выполняется .cmd файл, просто офигивает, мол, таких не держим, проверь идентификатор безопасности и имя пользователя. (Разбираюсь в XML чуть меньше, чем никак.) 
Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы имя пользователя и идентификатор безопасности менялись в зависимости от пользователя ПК?

Comment: Можно код сюда перетащить?